# Javamail - How to get default email address of the user?

Tags: jakarta-mail

I can already successfully send email with Javamail API.

A problem is i must give the sender's address by using message.setFrom(InternetAddress add);

I found out that the address must NOT be correct, i can give any address like (nosuch@fake.com)

How can i get the default email Address (like someone@somewhere.com) from the server?

(I dont want the software end-user give a email address by them self, which can be misused as a fake email)

The server is logined with username and password.(Username is not address like username@server.com but simply a name)

Thanks for everyone my help!!

Comment: What do you mean by "default"?

Comment: just the normal real one. like i log in my yahoo webmail and compose a email,click send. the receiver will get my email with the address i registered by yahoo. If i allow user give email address by themself,they can give fake instead of real.

Comment: That's because you registered it with yahoo. You could simply add @mail.yourserver.com to usernames and make valid email addresses

Comment: Problem is, i am developing a email client for a specific server (not yahoo) of my school. The server has different address for different user. like someone log in as someone@teacher.school.com, someother is someother@student.school.com. I can't judge from the login username , it is simply as "someone"

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to know **for sure**.

You can make some assumptions that work in some environments.  For example, if the username doesn't include "@", the email address is username@servername.  Obviously that's not true everywhere.

You could look at all the messages in the INBOX and try to guess which of the recipients is the current user, but there may be no messages or they may not name the recipient directly (mailing lists).